# How to get multiple image array using API or PHP query

Tags: craft3, php

This is a single asset field to upload multiple images so how to get all images using the query.
[image]

I have three images here but I am getting one image using this code

```
$home = \craft\elements\Entry::find()
  ->section($section)->site(Craft::$app->request->getQueryParam('lang'))
  ->one();
  
  foreach ($home->infographics as $key => $infographicsValue) {
        $infographicsImage[$key]['image'] = $infographicsValue->infographicsImage;
    }
```

Output

```
{"results":[{"data":{"infographicsImage":[{"image":{"dimensions":{"width":"374","height":"370"},"alt":"Dyk3","copyright":null,"url":"https://lenz-dev-asset.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/ecovero/dyk3.jpg"}}]}}]}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thank you!!

Comment: Can you add more of your code? The output looks like you are using [Element API](https://plugins.craftcms.com/element-api).

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Previous answer was incorrect, see update below.

What kind of field is `infographics`? How is it related to the `infographicsImage` field you're accessing in the loop?

Either way, one of those is the assets field. Accessing an [Assets field](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/assets-fields.html) by handle returns an [AssetQuery](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-db-assetquery.html), not an [Asset](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-asset.html) itself. To access the resulting assets, you need to execute the query using `->one()` or `->all()`, which will give you either a single Asset object (or null) or an array of Asset objects (which may be empty).

Please provide more info regarding the fields.

Comment: I can't find the field 'infographics' of a particular section using the `craft\elements\Asset`

Comment: @SantanuAdak My answer was incorrect, I've misread the code in your question. Either way, you're not executing the asset query correctly, see my updated answer. If you provide more information, I can provide a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue with this code

```
foreach ($home->infographics as $key => $infographicsValue) {
      
     $imageArr['width'] = $infographicsValue['width'] ? $infographicsValue['width'] : "";
     $imageArr['height'] = $infographicsValue['height'] ? $infographicsValue['height'] : "";
     $imageArr['alt'] = $infographicsValue['title'] ? $infographicsValue['title'] : "";
     $imageArr['url'] = $infographicsValue['url'] ? $infographicsValue['url'] : "";
      
     $infographicsImage[$key]['image'] = $imageArr;
  }
```